# Google search turns up weird result?

Tags: discussion, google

I was trying to look for an explanation for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15303532/799558) that was posted less than an hour ago and have no answers till now. My [google search attempt](https://www.google.com.ly/#hl=en&safe=off&rlz=1C2TEUA_enLY495LY522&sclient=psy-ab&q=winforms+listbox+refreshes+combobox&oq=winforms+listbox+refreshes+combobox&gs_l=hp.3..33i29i30.40399.58782.0.59006.45.43.2.0.0.1.792.14528.3j0j17j10j1j5j4.40.0.les%3B..3.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.r5n9xhYxgRU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.ZWU&fp=8c6deed726f743b1&biw=1366&bih=667) returned the same question as the first result, but claiming that the question was asked 13 hours ago and have two answers already!

[image]

Where is google getting this information from? and why is it not accurate ?

Comment: Google is faaaaaaaaast indexing SO.

Comment: So fast it knew the question would be posted 13 hours ago and it predicts 2 answers.

Comment: The title's wrong too, it should start with c# not vb.net.

Comment: @blahdiblah: The [tag:c#] tag was [added in later](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15303532/revisions). Google probably hadn't updated the title  yet.

Comment: Google is the fastest gun in the west