# Why do some questions not appear in Google results?

Tags: support, search, google

There are two very similar questions on SO (but not identical).  Both contain the term "Derby" in the title and the word "datediff" in the question.

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324522/how-to-get-the-hour-difference-between-2-datetimestamp-on-derby-db)

[Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511805/using-timestampdiff-in-a-derby-where-clause)

When I searched Google for "derby datediff" (without limiting the search to Stack Overflow), only Post 1 shows up.  To see Post 2 I have to search StackOverflow.

I am curious, what about Post 2 causes it not to appear in the Google results?  Is it too new?  Is it not upvoted enough?  Is it because the word "datediff" appears in a code block?  Has it not been viewed enough times?

Comment: Sounds like a question for meta.google.com

Comment: Google [definitely indexes it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22How+to+get+the+hour+difference+between+2+datetimestamp+on+derby+db%3F%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk&redir_esc=&ei=g0BEUaKIDOev0QW924HgBw), but being > 2 years since there was activity I'd guess they don't rank it so high.

Comment: @Flexo:  What qualifies as activity from Google's point of view?  Comments/answers?  Upvotes?  Views?

Comment: AFAIK, Google indexes new questions pretty quickly, and even [predicts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171004/208592) the number of answers the question will get :P